# Randomness on Interstitial ads

Tags: android, admob

Is it allowed to show interstitial ads based on Android's Random variable? to not annoy people.

```
ad = new InterstitialAd(this);
Random random = new Random();
if(random.nextInt(4) == 0) {//25% chance to show ad
    ad.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_id));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    ad.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

or randomness is bad with ad, please don't block this post i really need an answer.

Comment: yes randomness is bad with ad. Instead of that you can do like on click count, for example in your screen any button click, count clicks and save count when count equals  4, show interstitial ads and make saved count 0. This way you can do. Let me know if didn't get.

Comment: I'm showing the interstitial ad when pressing back button and returning to the main page (not exiting the app)

Comment: ok. So you want something like show ad on back random click(sometimes after 3 click sometimes after 5) not every time on back right?

Comment: I think i'll just make it show the ad every single time, if randomness is bad then

Comment: every single time is also fine and as i said above on specific count is also fine.